# Git with SSH hangs

Tags: git, ssh

I have a strange problem with git and SSH.

I am able to authenticate:

```
$ ssh -T git@github.com
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
Hi matteocorti! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

But `git` hangs:

```
$ export GIT_TRACE=1
$ git pull
13:14:16.097981 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git pull
13:14:16.103679 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: git fetch --update-head-ok
13:14:16.108568 git.c:460               trace: built-in: git fetch --update-head-ok
13:14:16.113055 run-command.c:654       trace: run_command: unset GIT_PREFIX; GIT_PROTOCOL=version=2 ssh -o SendEnv=GIT_PROTOCOL git@github.com 'git-upload-pack '\''matteocorti/check_ssl_cert.git'\'''
```

The issue is not dependent on the repository (I have the issue with SSH on GitHub and an internal GitLab instance). Via HTTPS, everything works.

What could the issue be as SSH is connecting?

Comment: Interesting - the diagnostic message about X11 forwarding is probably discombobulating Git somehow.

Comment: @torek I would investigate but since it's years that I don't use X11 forwarding, I just removed the setting :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -vvv"` I was able to see

```
debug2: client_x11_get_proto: xauth command: /opt/X11/bin/xauth -f /var/folders/ky/kv1ztfnn6sl9bh5w_0s633pc0000gn/T//ssh-69i9YB86QAmF/xauthfile generate /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.khLHXhlQT8/org.xquartz:0 MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 untrusted timeout 1260 2>/dev/null
```

Disabling `ForwardX11 yes` in `.ssh/config` solved the problem